# How to run ksize.py tool of Yocto when build a core-image-minimal image?

Tags: kernel, yocto, rootfs

I want to further reduce the kernel and rootfs of the core-image-minimal build to adapt to our minimal application. The core-image-minimal build does not create a build directory and vmlinux so I cannot use ksize.py to examine it. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
devtool modify linux-imx
devtool build linux-imx
```

The kernel could be something else than linux-imx

Go to the kernel build directory. I find it easier to look for the 'built-in.o' file than to remember the path.

```
cd build
find . -name 'built-in.o'
cd to something like tmp/work/.../linux-imx/../build
```

I think 'ksize.py' doesn't run well with python3.

```
python2 .../sources/poky/scripts/tiny/ksize.py
```

Comment: In the Dunfell release of yocto, ksize is working with Python3.  But, it looks like (at least for the kernel I'm using) the built-in.o files are now renamed ot built-in.a.